# MySQL root password not in mysqld.log

Tags: mysql, linux, root, mysqladmin

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.7.18 on Fedora 25.

I'm following this link: https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

I get stuck on here on step 5: grep 'A temporary password is generated for root@localhost' /var/log/mysqld.log |tail -1

I get no output and I checked the logs, there no password. I also checked if MySQL is running.

I also have log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log in /etc/my.cnf

Comment: What version of MySQL are you trying to install? Versions prior to 5.6 don't generate a root password or write it in the log.

Comment: So try logging in user `root` with no password. Does that work

Comment: In my experience, Fedora's mysql setup results in a passwordless `root` account (it's been a little while though).

Comment: @BillKarwin 5.7.18

Comment: @RiggsFolly tried

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @RiggsFolly everytime it asks for user root password, i get "Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)". There suppose to be a temp password in mysqld.log

Comment: Have you tried running `mysqladmin -u root password yournewpasswordhere`? Although I would expect this to ask for the old password :(.

Comment: This doc may help you reset the root password https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/reset-mysql-root-password.

Answer (score 1):

it means there is no password generated in your log file, so just press enter without any password